# Well Ordering Principle sum of natural Numbers help

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation, natural-numbers, well-orders

I was reading over the following solution for the sum of all natural numbers using the well-ordering principle.

Let Fact 1 be:

$$\forall n:\ (1+2+3+...n)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

By contradiction, assume that Fact 1 is false. Then, some nonnegative integers serve as counterexamples to it. Let’s collect them in a set:

$$C= \left\{ n \in \mathbb{N} \mid (1+2+3+...n) \neq \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \right\}$$

Assuming there are counterexamples, $C$ is a nonempty set of nonnegative integers. So, by the well-ordering principle, $C$ has a minimum element, which we’ll call $c$. That is, among the nonnegative integers, $c$ is the smallest counterexample to Fact 1.

Since $c$ is the smallest counterexample, we know that Fact 1 is false for $n=c$ but true for all nonnegative integers $n<c$. But Fact 1 is true for $n=0$, so $c>0$. This means $c - 1$ is a nonnegative integer, and since it is less than $c$, Fact 1 is true for $c - 1$. That is,

$$(1+2+3+...c-1)=\frac{c(c-1)}{2}$$

But then, adding $c$ to both sides, we get

$$(1+2+3+...+(c-1)+c)=\frac{c(c-1)}{2} + c = \frac{c(c+1)}{2}$$

which means that (Fact 1) does hold for $c$, after all! This is a contradiction.

I am confused when the proof states "Since $c$ is the smallest counterexample, we know that Fact 1 is false for $n=c$ but true for all nonnegative integers $n<c$." How can we assume this? All we know is that Fact 1 is false when $n=c$, it does not say anything about it being true. I am a beginner when it comes to discrete math so keep that in mind during an explanation. Thanks!

Comment: The sentence you quote needs no proof, this is exactly what the words "smallest counterexample" mean.

Comment: In the def of $C$ I think you have $\ne$.

Comment: Having said that, **IF** we assume that the fact does not hold, this means tmhat $C$ is not empty; thus - by the WOP - it has a minimum element $c$. This means that $c \in C$ and that - being the minimum - there are no other numbers less tmhan $c$ that belongs to $C$. This again means that $c-1$ (being lesser than $c$) will satisfies the property.

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to a proof via induction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Equivalence_with_the_well-ordering_principle.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA if we assume c is the minimum element that satisfies C I don't understand why we are allowed to say c-1 will also satisfy C since we already assumed that c is the least element?

Comment: @MartinR can you further explain how this is similar to simple induction? I'm struggling to understand the similarities.

Comment: The "trick" of the proof that you have to grasp (see your error discussed above) is that the set $C$ is defined with the **negation** of the property expressed by Fact1 : the property we want to prove. Thus, if $c$ is the least number in $C$, it means that $c-1$ is **not** in $C$ and thus this mean that $c-1$ will satisfy Fact1.

Comment: Now, the proof will find the contradiction, showing that if $c-1$ satisfies Fact1, also $c$ will satisfy it, contrary to the assumption.

Comment: It is "similar" to Mathematical Induction, because we can prove that MI and WOP are equivalent (each one can be proved from the other.

Comment: The proof by induction is simple : check that Fact1 holds for $n=1 : 1=\dfrac {1(1+1)}{2}$.

Comment: THen assume for $n=k$ and check it for $n=k+1$, that means perform the same computation above : $(1+2+ \ldots +k)+(k+1)= \dfrac {k(k+1)}{2} + (k+1)$, by Induction Hypotheses, and then compute the RHS to find  $\dfrac {(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$.